# Button switch Arduino to Processing: serial output giving null

Tags: arduino, processing

I am trying to use a button switch in Arduino to trigger a visual display in Processing. I used "HIGH" and "LOW" to identify whether the button is pressed.

However, my code is constantly giving null instead of giving "HIGH" or "LOW" depending on the button state. I think this is pretty basic but I'm just quite lost. Any helps or comments would be appreciated!

Below is my code for Arduino and Processing respectively.

```cpp
const int buttonPin = 2; 
const int LEDPin = 13; 

int buttonState = 0; 

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(LEDPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int analogValue = analogRead(A0)/4;
  Serial.write(analogValue);
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    Serial.write(HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LEDPin, HIGH);
  } else {
    Serial.write(LOW);
    digitalWrite(LEDPin, LOW);
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

Processing code:

```java
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;
String val; 

void setup() {
  size(400,400);
  String portName = Serial.list()[1];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw() {
  if (myPort.available() > 0) {
    val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
    println(val);
    if (val == "HIGH") {
      background(127,0,0);
    }
    if (val == "LOW") {
      background(144, 26, 251);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Serial.write(HIGH);` doesn't send `'H'`,`'I'`,`'G'`,`'H'` and `'\n'` but just a `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[write()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write)**

Writes binary data to the serial port. This data is sent as a byte or series of bytes.

```cpp
Serial.write(str)
```

str: a string to send as a series of bytes

---

So when you use write `HIGH` and `LOW` in `Serial.write`, it will be send as a series of bytes. Edit your processing part to handle the incoming bytes. Just as follows :

```java
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;
String val; 
int len; //length of byte array

void setup() {
  size(400,400);
  String portName = Serial.list()[1];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw() {
  if ((len=myPort.available()) > 0) {
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
      myByteArray=myPort.read();
    String val = String(myByteArray);
    println(val);
    if (val == "HIGH") {
      background(127,0,0);
    }
    if (val == "LOW") {
      background(144, 26, 251);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. `HIGH` and `LOW` will be sent as a single byte 1 and 0. Also this isn't really a reliable way of reading a complete string.

Answer (score 2):

just change your buttonState variable type from integer to boolean, and then use

```
if(buttonState) {
       Serial.println("HIGH");
}
else {
      Serial.println("LOW");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Arduino, `HIGH` and `LOW` [are defined](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Arduino.h#L40-L41) as 1 and 0.

By executing `Serial.write(HIGH);` and `Serial.write(LOW);` you are just sending a single byte 1 or 0.

But according to your Processing code, you are expecting `Serial.write(HIGH);` to send `'H'`, `'I'`, `'G'`, `'H'` and `'\n'` characters.

In your Arduino code, you need to replace `Serial.write(HIGH);` and `Serial.write(LOW);` with `Serial.print("HIGH\n");` and `Serial.print("LOW\n");`.